# Blank pages after conversion images to pdf using Apache PDFBox.

Tags: apache, pdf, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox for conversion images(png, jpg) to pdf and the issue is that document pages are blank after following operations:

```
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        for (BufferedImage buff : list) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight()));
            doc.addPage(page);
            PDXObjectImage ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, buff);
            PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
            content.drawImage(ximage, 0, 0);
            content.close();
        }
        doc.save(outStream);
        doc.close();
```

Can somebody help with that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with position 200, 200. What happens?

Comment: Hi, Tilman! Thanks again for help with [this question](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2361) :)